# Problem with 2 simultaneous connection with PDO/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my simplified code:

```
$connexion = new PDO(SQL_DSN,SQL_USERNAME,SQL_PASSWORD);
$connexion2 = new PDO(SQL_DSN2,SQL_USERNAME2,SQL_PASSWORD2);

[...]

$sqlIndex = "SELECT index_key,index_platforms_code
             FROM   index
             WHERE  index_missions_id = :mission";
$initFiches = $connexion->prepare($sqlIndex);
$initFiches->bindParam(":mission" , $_GET['mission']);
$initFiches->execute();
try 
{
    while ($fiche = $initFiches->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        print_r($fiche);

        foreach ($structure['champs'] as $masterChamp)
        {
            //$stmt = $connexion2->prepare($masterChamp['sql']);
        }
    }
}
    catch (exception $e)
    {
        echo "error".$e->getMessage();

    }
```

My output:

```
Array
(
    [index_key] => 1
    [index_platforms_code] => 1
)
Array
(
    [index_key] => 2
    [index_platforms_code] => 2
)
Array
(
    [index_key] => 3
    [index_platforms_code] => 3
)
Array
(
    [index_key] => 4
    [index_platforms_code] => 4
)
```

All Right, but if I uncomment this line

```
$stmt = $connexion2->prepare($masterChamp['sql']);
```

in the foreach, this line broke the while above and here is the new output:

```
Array
(
    [index_key] => 1
    [index_platforms_code] => 1
)
```

Someone have an idea?

Comment: Should'nt really cause problems ( I do this all the time too for same reason different physical db's), should work. Are you sure the 2 connections are created? Are you actually getting a specific error? try wrapping in a try catch to get any errors...

Comment: try catch dont show any error... And the connections are both OK, I verified that by displaying the query result

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't involve 2 connections and that's more optimized.

```
$connexion = new PDO(SQL_DSN,SQL_USERNAME,SQL_PASSWORD);
$sqlIndex = "SELECT index_key,index_platforms_code
             FROM   index
             WHERE  index_missions_id = :mission";

$initFiches = $connexion->prepare($sqlIndex);

$initFiches->bindParam(":mission" , $_GET['mission'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$initFiches->execute();

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $connexion->prepare("SELECT ...."); // Prepare outside of the loop, you don't have to prepare it X times, once is enough.

if(sizeof($data))
{
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        // Do your statement binding / executing.    
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it seems you might be able to do this with table joining rather than issuing a query for each row you get from the 1st table. Since you haven't posted the structure, I guess there's no much helping it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i use two connections because it is realy two mtsql database, on two different servers...

Comment: Even with two different databases, you shouldn't prepare a statement within a loop, do it outside of a loop. In order to find out what's happening really, set PDO to exception mode and use try / catch block to catch any exceptions that occur. Your code doesn't really show what happens in case of an error.

Comment: Oo I need to say that in my real code, the query I prepare is stocked on the 'structure['champs'] array, and there is different queries foreach structure['champs'].. so How can I i exit the prepare ?

Comment: In that case you can't, but that's a whole different scenario then as it has no similarities to the initial problem you described :)